# Quick question: SES where base ring is a PID

Tags: modules, principal-ideal-domains

Let $M$ be an $R$-module, where $R$ is a PID. Assume there is a free $R$-module $F$ and a surjective map $\phi :F\rightarrow M$. Then why is $\ker(\phi)$ also free?

Thank you.

Comment: No need to assume that there is such $\phi$ because we always have it.

Answer (score 2):

Because any submodule of a free module over a PID is free.

You can learn about that [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162945/submodule-of-free-module-over-a-p-i-d-free-even-when-the-module-is-not-finitely).