# Is any Direct Summand of a Free Module over a PID also Free?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, principal-ideal-domains

> Let $R$ be a PID and $F$ be a free module over $R$. Suppose we have $F=A\oplus B$ for some $R$-modules $A$ and $B$. Then are $A$ and $B$ necessarily free?

If $F$ is finitely generated, then I know that $A$ too is finitely generated. Thus we can write $A$ as a direct sum of a torsion module and a free module. Since there is no torsion in $F$, the torsion part of $A$ must be zero. Thus $A$ must be free and same for $B$.

Is the statement true even when $F$ is not finitely generated?

Comment: Any submodule of a free module over a PID is free, regardless of whether the free module is finitely generated or not. The proof is not trivial, you can find one [here](http://www.math.washington.edu/~palmieri/Courses/2004/Math506/free.pdf).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submodule of free module over a p.i.d. is free even when the module is not finitely generated?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162945/submodule-of-free-module-over-a-p-i-d-is-free-even-when-the-module-is-not-finit)