# If $P$ is projective and $A,B$ are direct summands of $P$ then $A\cap B$ is a direct summand of $P$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, projective-module

I need to prove that if $P$ is a projective module over $\mathbb Z$ and $A,B$ are direct summands of $P$ then $A\cap B$ is a direct summand of $P$.

This in turn would imply if $A$ and $B$ are projective then $A\cap B$ is projective. (Since $A$ and $B$ would be direct summands of $A+B$ which is clearly also projective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have an exact sequence $0\to P/A\cap B\stackrel{f}\to P/A\oplus P/B$. (Define $f(x)=(x,-x)$.) Then $P/A\cap B$ is a submodule of a projective module which over $\mathbb Z$ is free, so $P/A\cap B$ is also free.

Comment: Thanks, we had started to see this in with the TA but I forgot. Just out of curiosity, did you take this out of some book or notes or something?

Comment: The short exact sequence $0\to P/A\cap B\to P/A\oplus P/B\to P/(A+B)\to 0$ is well known.

Comment: One question, how does the fact that $P/A\cap B$ is free imply $A\cap B$ is a direct summand of $P$?

Comment: Free $\implies$ projective and use the short exact sequence $0\to A\cap B\to P\to P/A\cap B\to 0$.

Comment: Ok, I know every summand of a  projective module is projective, but does the converse hold?

Comment: I've thought that [this property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_module#Split-exact_sequences) is well known.

Comment: Why is a submodule of a projective module over $\mathbb Z$ free?

Comment: @dREaM See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162945/submodule-of-free-module-over-a-p-i-d-is-free-even-when-the-module-is-not-finit. So, over $\mathbb Z$ (or over a PID) any submodule of a free (=projective) module is free.