# Is the kernel of a map from a $\mathbb{Z}$-free module to an abelian group $\mathbb{Z}$-free?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

Is the kernel of a map from a $\mathbb{Z}$-free module to an abelian group $\mathbb{Z}$-free?
It seems like the answer should be yes as the kernel is contained inside the free $\mathbb{Z}$-module but I can't quite put my finger on the precise reason why.

Comment: Submodules of free modules over a pid (like $\mathbb{Z}$) are free, so yes.

Comment: For example, see here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162945/submodule-of-free-module-over-a-p-i-d-is-free-even-when-the-module-is-not-finit