Does "every submodule of a free module under a PID is free" imply the Axiom of choice?
It is a fact that under the Axiom of choice, every submodule of a free module under a PID is free. An outline of the proof is available at
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/162958/1389108
My question is, does the implication go the other way? Suppose I have the axioms of ZF + the statement that every submodule of a free module under a PID is free. Does this imply the Axiom of choice?
(The intuition for this question is that "every vector space has a basis" is equivalent to the Axiom of choice. So I have suspicions that the same might be true for this module condition.)

Not sure if this works, but: this implies a subspace of a free vector space (i.e. vector space with a basis) is itself free. If we could injectively map any vector space into some free vector space, it would mean that any vector space has a basis, and this fact is known to be equivalent to AC.

Embedding a vector space into a free vector space is equivalent to the statement that for every non-zero vector there is a linear functional that maps this vector to something non-zero (or $1$), i.e., that there are enough linear functionals. This is not provable in ZF.

@MartinBrandenburg Oh, I see, thanks!

About my comment, sorry it's not equivalent, but $\implies$ holds, which suffices here. I mixed up $K^I$ with $K^{\oplus I}$.
